# Wrap Text in UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitextfield, word-wrap

Does anyone know how to wrap text in a `UITextField`? I am using Cocoa/Objective-C in Xcode for my iPhone project, and I can not seem to find a way to do this...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) is meant for single-line text only. If you want multiple lines of text, then you'll have to use the [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) class instead.

It's worth noting that `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so if you don't want scrolling, you may want to stick with the `UITextField` and put up with the text being on one line... I once tried to subclass `UITextView` to make it like a multiple-line `UITextField`, but the `UIScrollView` made the task a nightmare—in the end I just went back to using a simple `UITextField`.

Comment: Yea, I hate the UITextView, so I'm just going to bear with the UITextField standards -_-

Comment: I switched off scroll and it works fine. textView.scrollEnabled = NO;